# Postgresql - splitting numbers and letters in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to split the following column in numbers and letters. Can someone please advise on how this can be achieved?

```
Duration
--------
90 Min
```

Comment: Why you want to do this from DB level, Frontend dev can also do this. 
i.g share all possible values and they can seprate with last 3 digits and other remain value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `SUBSTRING` here:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(duration FROM '^\d+') AS num,
       SUBSTRING(duration FROM '^\d+ (.*)') AS letter
FROM yourTable;
```